musl ld maps libc.so.6 to ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
/lib # ./ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 --list /usr/lib/libEGL.so.1
        ./ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f2b06797000)
        libdl.so.2 => ./ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f2b06797000)
        libm.so.6 => ./ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f2b06797000)
        libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x7f2b06000000)
        libc.so.6 => ./ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f2b06797000)
Error relocating /usr/lib/libGLdispatch.so.0: __strdup: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/libEGL.so.1: __strdup: symbol not found

I have set /etc/ld-musl-x86_64.path1 to include directory where libc.so.6 is located. I even tried moving libc.so.6 to /lib but it did not help. It still mislinks to ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 instead of the actual libc.so.6.
How can I make it use the actual libc.so.6?

https://wiki.musl-libc.org/faq


Does it look like musl does it on purpose? https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/ldso/dynlink.c#n1075

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709030/what-is-libc-start-main-and-start

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476533/why-is-statically-linking-glibc-discouraged

In musl, the dynamic loader (ld-musl-x86_64.so.1) is the same binary as C library. All the libraries which are shipped in the musl C library (libc, libpthread, librt, libm, libdl, libutil, libxnet, as you discovered) are resolved using the dynamic loader, since it’s already loaded.
Tying the loader to the library in this way makes explicit the reality of other C libraries: the dynamic loader is part of the C library, whether it’s the same binary or not. The GNU dynamic loader works with the GNU C library, the musl dynamic loader works with the musl C library, they aren’t interchangeable in general.

Not only that, if the library contains __libc_start_main and stdin symbols it gets replaced as well! https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/ldso/dynlink.c?id=007997299248b8682dcbb73595c53dfe86071c83#n1194
